# Piping output to be displayed

Tags: bash, unix, piping

I'm trying to write a simple bash script to print out a specific group of users currently using a machine.

I use the command "who" to generate the currently logged in users, then try to pipe in an echo command with a wildcard.

What about this format is incorrect?

```
who | echo [A-D]*
```

Comment: Try to be more specific about the desired result.  Do you want entire line output of any user starting with `[A-Z]` or only one or more usernames starting with `[A-Z]`? This link should help: http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo` does not read  `stdin`. It just prints given command line argument.

To filter input, use `grep` with a regular expression:

```
who | grep '[A-D]'
```

Above will filter `who` output, only print lines that contains `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
who | grep -e '^[A-D]'
```